# Android Studio syntax error on Location API

Tags: android, android-studio

I am creating a location app and I am getting some errors if anyone can help:

```
private LocationListen mListener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
         currentLocation = location;
         updateDisplay();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }
 };
```

In the above code on LocationListen is highlighted red but nothing else :S

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    currentLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    updateDisplay();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mListener);
}
```

The part that is highlighted red is "(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mListener)"

and

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(mListener);
}
```

mlistener is highlighted red. Not sure what the error is :S

Comment: Shouldn't it be ' private LocationListener mListener = new LocationListener() {...}' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some errors, change the first block in this:

```
private LocationListener mListener = new LocationListener(){
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location){
        currentLocation=location;
        updateDisplay();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){
    }
};
```

and the second block in this:

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    currentLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    updateDisplay();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mListener);
}
```

the third block should be correct now.

Comment: Firstly thank you for your suggest! And thank you for the help, it worked out 100%! You are awesome.

I am just wondering what was the difference?